# Pixelated 3d model in a screenshot from Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, screenshot

I'm taking a screenshot from an augmented reality app. The photo quality is high. But I also add 3d models on top of the photo, and the result is that they are pixelated. Any ideas how to tackle this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Anti-aliasing issue.

You can go to the Unity Settings/Quality:
There is a option of Anti Aliasing, you can increase them from "2x multi sampling" to higher sampling rate.

Meanwhile, there are some preset quality levels like "Very Low", "Low"..etc.
Please check if you have same Quality option in Editor and your Android Build. You should see a "green tick" of selected Quality of build platforms and editor. make sure they are in same quality levels.

After all those changes, and don't forget to turn on anti aliasing option in your Main Cam too.